# adding multiple functions inside $(document).ready

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of mutually exclusive actions on my page (form validation, and a confirmation box) the functions are not related or dependent on each other, so is it ok to put both in

```
$(document).ready
```

ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").validate();
  $("delete").confirm();
});
```

I assume that form and delete in this case or sibling functions, and since they are not nested they are not dependent, is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Have you encountered any problems?

Comment: Yes, correct except the function syntax. Leave ot the curly brackets at the end...

Comment: That will result in a syntax error. What are the curly braces for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call methods in the `$(document).ready` like that; if they aren't dependent on each other then it should work.

By the way, although that's just an example...the `{}` aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

If they are, as you say, not dependent on each other then there should be no problem in calling them both from `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, `$(document).ready` just says that your document's structure is ready and you can manipulate it. Your  `$("form")` and whatever elements are ready for use